# Debugging var = var2 == var3

Tags: c, debugging

I'm currently debugging a program for a school asignment and is currently stuck at understanding this line of code.

All variables are integers.

```
unfinished = count == 2;
```

Output of that is mainly 0, but does the "==" (comparison?) actually have an affect to the values or is it completly ignored?

Program language is C

Comment: Why are you writing code that is difficult to understand? Summat wrong with using brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) means that

```
unfinished = count == 2;
```

is evaluated as

```
unfinished = (count == 2);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if (count == 2)
    unfinished = 1;
else
    unfinished = 0;
```

Comment: Interesting, instead of `a = b == c? 1: 0`  we can use just `a = b == c` or only `a = (b == c)`

Answer (score 2):

if `count`is equal to 2, `unfinished` will be 1 (true), else it will be 0 (false)

Comment: *Right of the = is evaluated first*: No. No guarantee that right operand of `=` operator evaluates first. Order of evaluation is not guaranteed with this operator.

Comment: This table say it is http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: Are you mixing Associativity with order of evaluation?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Precedence does not guarantee order of evaluation; the result of `count == 2` must be evaluated before it can be *assigned* to `unfinished`, but that doesn't mean `unfinished` can't be evaluated first.

Comment: I think you are confused with **associativity** and **order of evaluation**. Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx?Redirected=true) article by [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).

Comment: I have done some reading and came the the conclusion i was indeed mixing up some words.. thanks for correcting me :-)